# Crash on NSMutableDictionary's setObject function

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash

Here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"dictionaryPlayers=%@,%d",[dictionaryPlayers description],dictionaryPlayers.count);
[dictionaryPlayers setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test2"];
```

dictionaryPlayers is inited in this class's init function:

```
-(id)init{
  ...
  dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10]retain];
  ...
}
```

The program crashed:

```
Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGABRT".
```

And in console:

```
2011-12-27 17:01:21.744 [25454:207] dictionaryPlayers={
},0
2011-12-27 17:01:21.745 [25454:207] -[__NSCFConstantString tick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x199bcc
```

With the NSLog outputs, i think dictionaryPlayers is well inited. So I don't know why crashed...

Comment: [dictionaryPlayers setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test2"]; for which index?

Comment: yes...there is no problem there...anywhere else you are accessing that dictionary?

Comment: wasn't able to reproduce the same behaviour.

Comment: but when i commented the setObject line, it works fine...

Comment: ya..it was fine. My mistake. I don't find that code with problem.May be you are making some other mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The object on which you call tick: is not longer in memory and causes this crash. Try to see why this object is released.

Comment: the problem is , if i commented this line:

Comment: the problem is, if i commented "[dictionaryPlayers setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test2"]; ", the program works fine. but with the log line, it shows dictinaryPlayers is not released.

Comment: How do you Check Object retain state ? To release an Object does not mean its reference is nil. In your case the object is in the autorelease pool.

Comment: as shown above, in init() I retained dictionaryPlayers, and never manually released it, so it should not be released when I add object into it.

Comment: BTW, how to check a object is not released?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not a local case, so did you make sure to synthesize it at the top? And declared it correctly in the header? Examples:
In header:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryPlayers;
```

in class:

```
@synthesize dictionaryPlayers = _dictionaryPlayers;
```

Comment: I checked it:

    "at"property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryPlayers;
    "at"synthesize dictionaryPlayers;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call retain on the object in your init statement.  Also just for giggles try:

```
dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
dictionaryPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
```

And do this right above your log statement (take it out of the init).

If this works, put a log in your init method and make sure that is being called before your method that adds KV's to the dictionary

I cannot reproduce this behavior.  Here is my code:
ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryPlayers;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *logTextView;
- (IBAction)logButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize dictionaryPlayers;
@synthesize logTextView;


#pragma mark - My Methods
- (IBAction)logButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    logTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d",[dictionaryPlayers description],[dictionaryPlayers count]];
    NSLog(@"dictionaryPlayers=%@,%d",[dictionaryPlayers description],[dictionaryPlayers count]);
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    [dictionaryPlayers setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"testKey"];
    NSLog(@"dictionaryPlayers=%@,%d",[dictionaryPlayers description],[dictionaryPlayers count]);
}
```

No issues.  If you are doing things this way, you cannot have problems.  Here are the steps I would take to troubleshoot further:

1. Do a project search for playersDictionary and make sure there isn't something else touching that object.
2. Try cleaning the project
3. Create a new project with this structure and see what happens

Comment: I removed

    dictionaryPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];

from init(), and add

    dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

before my log statement. Still crash....
Then I removed 

    [dicTest setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"testKey"];

Then there's only 

    dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"dictionaryPlayers=%@,%d",[dictionaryPlayers description],dictionaryPlayers.count);

, It didn't crash. So, it seems the setValue line really is the problem.

Comment: BTW, if i remove retain, it will soon crash with output "message sent to deallocated instance"

Comment: [dicTest setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"testKey"]; should be [dictionaryPlayers setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"testKey"];

Comment: sorry , i copied mistake, it is dictionaryPlayers.

Comment: @ZephyrZhang - Added more to the answer above

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
dictionaryPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
```

from init(), and added

```
dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

above my log statement. Still crash.... 
Then I removed

```
[dicTest setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"testKey"];
```

So there's only 2 lines left:

```
dictionaryPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSLog(@"dictionaryPlayers=%@,%d",[dictionaryPlayers description],dictionaryPlayers.count);
```

It didn't crash. So, it seems the setValue line really is the problem.